# Send a file to Winsock socket with curl utility

Tags: http, curl, tcp, udp, winsock

I need to send a file to an HTTP server with the *curl* utility. However, as my server application only needs to process a single file, I'd like to avoid using some large HTTP framework with a wide range of functionality, so I'd like to stick to TCP/UDP protocols with some simple HTTP parser.

A file to send to the server may be quite large and I doubt if it is reasonable to send this file as a single TCP packet, so I'm dreaming of splitting this file into UDP packets and sending them one by one. But on the client side, all this must be done with a simple curl command, like `curl --data-binary @filename 127.0.0.1:80`.

Is it possible to split this request into several packets using *WinSock API*? For example, the server reads the name of a file, detects its size, allocates as many packets as needed and starts receiving UDP packets. Or maybe should I look at other ways of solving it?

Comment: Any ideas or sth?..

Comment: "*I'm dreaming of splitting this file into UDP packets and sending them one by one*" - that is completely unnecessary, and potentially very lossy (unless you use a UDP-based file transfer protocol, like TFTP). HTTP over TCP will handle large files just fine. There are plenty of examples on SO of writing a simple HTTP parser, regardless of how the underlying socket breaks up data into individual network packets.

Comment: I just found out TCP handles large files pretty well